# iPhone X - Set the color of the area around home indicator

Tags: ios, xcode, indicator, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

I'm pretty much new to Xcode when trying to align a sheet to the safe area of iPhone X, it leaves a transparent area below the sheet.

Is there a way to set the fill of that area w/o expanding the sheet or align outside of the safe area?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is my tiny extension.
If anybody can suggest an improvement to not access added view by "magic number" tag - welcome!

```
extension UIViewController {

private static let insetBackgroundViewTag = 98721 //Cool number

func paintSafeAreaBottomInset(withColor color: UIColor) {
    guard #available(iOS 11.0, *) else {
        return
    }
    if let insetView = view.viewWithTag(UIViewController.insetBackgroundViewTag) {
        insetView.backgroundColor = color
        return
    }

    let insetView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    insetView.tag = UIViewController.insetBackgroundViewTag
    insetView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(insetView)
    view.sendSubview(toBack: insetView)

    insetView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    insetView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    insetView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    insetView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    insetView.backgroundColor = color
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's not a good idea but can be a solution to your problem.

Follow this steps:

- Enable 'Safe Area Layout'
- Create/add a view (i.e. name it bottomPaddingView)  (Programtically or using storyboard) with background color, same as your sheet color.
- Position it (using following constraints - following constraints are not a code structure, but just showing a constraint/anchor relationship)

  -  bottomPaddingView.bottom = self.view.bottom

  -  bottomPaddingView.trailing = self.view.trailing

  -  bottomPaddingView.leading = self.view.leading

  -  bottomPaddingView.top = self.view.safeAreaLayoutConstraint.bottom // If you've enabled 'Safe Area Layout'

  -  **or** bottomPaddingView.top = self.view.bottomLayoutguide // If you've not enabled 'Safe Area Layout'

Now hide/unhide your `bottomPaddingView` with respect to actionship visibility with fade animation.