# iPhone X Keyboard Controller Background Color

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, background-color, iphone-x

How can you change the background color of the area around the keyboard on iPhone X? In this case, the gray area around the light blue.

[image]

I've tried

```
self.view.backgroundColor = self.keyboard.backgroundColor;
self.view.superview.backgroundColor = self.keyboard.backgroundColor;
```

even tried

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Nothing. Since the keyboard is clipped to it's containing box, you can't expand the view passed the expected frame. Thoughts?

**EDIT:**

The only thing I can think of is perhaps adding views to the appropriate positions to "cover" the background color but I don't think that's a valid solution to the problem..

**FYI:**

Yes. This question was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354227/how-to-change-the-bottom-edge-color-on-the-iphone-x-programmatically) but it was never answered so I figured I would try.

Answer (score 0):

I found `C9CCD3` to be pretty close. To set it:

[image: How to set by hex]

Not professional but it works.

Also bare in mind that the goal color has a transparency / vibrancy effect, and it may change according to what's behind it. Mine was tested for white background, like in Messages.

Comment: I'm very confused with your answer - I was not struggling to find a color, rather I was and still am searching for the answer regarding whether you can or can not (for now) **change** the gray background for a keyboard view controller on the iPhone X layout..

Comment: Oh, my bad! You were clear. This is what happens when you're sick but still go to work instead of resting at home :)

Comment: No worries - shame apple makes things like this so difficult lol